# hooking up events to vertical scroll bar upper arrows and down arrows in data grid view using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, vertical-scrolling

I have a datagrid view like this....in below image well thats works fine...

I need to hook up an event in vertical side bar ..

i mean if i click on upper arrow in the scroll bar i want to do something ...

If i click on the down arrow in that scroll bar , i want to do something...

To be more specific i want to get the id of first upper record when i click on upper arrow in  vertical scroll bar..

How can i do this... , I am using winforms

would any one pls help on this....

Many thanks in advance[image]

**I have found this but i dont know how to implement this in my page**

```
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

bool addScrollListener(DataGridView dgv)
{
bool ret = false;

Type t = dgv.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("VerticalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
ScrollBar s = null;

if (pi != null)
    s = pi.GetValue(dgv, null) as ScrollBar;

if (s != null)
{
    s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);
    ret = true;
}

return ret;
}

 void s_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
 {
 // Hander goes here..
 }
```

I have done like this...

```
private void s_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition)
        {
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement)
            {

                int i = dgvMembers.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
                int idemebers =Convert.ToInt32(dgvMembers.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
                getMemberInfo(i, idemebers);

            }
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
            {
                int i = dgvMembers.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
                int idemebers = Convert.ToInt32(dgvMembers.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
                getMemberInfo(i, idemebers);
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

but this event does not fire    s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);
it does not goes into the this event ...

would any one pls help on this...

Comment: You may end up creating your own custom scroll bar... I don't think Windows exposes these types of events.

Comment: @SpikeX i am using above code but dont know how to start....

Comment: That code won't work. It's an event for when the whole grid scrolls, not when you specifically click one of the up or down arrows.

Comment: would you pls take alook at  my modified code the event does not firing ..

Comment: @SpikeX pls take alook at my modified question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the code you have posted.  All you need to do is call `addScrollListener` somewhere (for example in your constructor after `InitializeComponent`)

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     // Replace dataGridView1 with the name of your DataGridView
     addScrollListener(dataGridView1);  
  }

  // addScrollListener code goes here
```

Comment: He wants separate events for when you scroll up vs. when you scroll down, so just adding a scroll listener doesn't do what he wants.